# Adding interaction effect in glmer model leads to convergence issues and unreasonable results

Tags: r, regression, convergence

I am attempting to run a Mixed-Effects Logistic Regression in R, using the glmer function to predict the choice (0 = reject vs. 1 = accept) of a certain offer in an experimental task on a trial-by-trial structure. The predictors (or fixed effects) include the **condition** (3-level factor), the **reward** (numeric) and the **costs** (numeric) of the current trial. I'm also using a random intercept for the subject.

Initially, when running the full model with all interactions, I found that all predictors were highly significant, which was surprising.

```
glmer(Choice ~ Condition * Reward * Cost + (1|Subject), 
                   data = data, family = 'binomial', 
                   control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

The model failed to converge, thus, I tried a simpler model by gradually adding more predictors to identify the problem. It seems that the model only converges and gives reasonable results if I do **not** include the Condition x Reward interaction.

Running the model without this interaction, I get these results:

```
(Intercept)       3.15906    0.16856  18.742  < 2e-16 ***
CondB            -0.07714    0.08023  -0.962  0.33628    
CondC            -0.14820    0.19012  -0.780  0.43568    
COST             -0.72789    0.07212 -10.093  < 2e-16 ***
REWARD            4.69425    0.07540  62.257  < 2e-16 ***
CondB:COST         0.08082    0.03530   2.289  0.02206 *  
CondC:COST        0.11315    0.03602   3.142  0.00168 ** 
COST:REWARD      -0.49778    0.05721  -8.701  < 2e-16 ***
```

When running the model without this interaction, I obtain results that show no convergence issues.

However, adding the interaction effect causes the model to fail to converge and gives different estimates for the main effect of condition and each condition interaction (e.g., -0.79 instead of -0.07 for Condition B), while the cost and reward estimates are not changed to the same degree.

```
(Intercept)       3.92337    0.07834  50.079  < 2e-16 ***
CondB            -0.79188    0.06142 -12.893  < 2e-16 ***
CondC            -1.43633    0.07344 -19.558  < 2e-16 ***
COST             -0.77109    0.05469 -14.100  < 2e-16 ***
REWARD            5.97786    0.06192  96.546  < 2e-16 ***
CondB:COST        0.13214    0.03280   4.028 5.62e-05 ***
CondC:COST        0.21043    0.03306   6.366 1.94e-10 ***
COST:REWARD      -0.46865    0.04644 -10.091  < 2e-16 ***
CondB:REWARD     -1.19364    0.07265 -16.430  < 2e-16 ***
CondC:REWARD     -2.28706    0.06707 -34.098  < 2e-16 ***
```

I am unsure of the problem and would appreciate any ideas or suggestions. Thank you in advance!